# How to initialize a 1 us timer on STM32?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

How can I choose a right prescaler/period value, to get 1 us counts?

I'm working with STM32F4 Dicovery board and I need to create a 1us counter and don't know, how I can decrease a steps.

I'm using TIM10.

10 us counts works:

```c
void 10_microSek_timer_Init() {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure;
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef TIM_OCInitStructure;

    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOB, GPIO_PinSource8, GPIO_AF_TIM10); // PB8 -> TIM10 Channel 1
  
    // TIM10 Clock enable
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM10, ENABLE);

    // Timer 10 Config PWM

    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Period = 10- 1; //Change Orig 1 Sek: 10000-1; 1ms: 10-1; 10ms: 100-1; 100ms: 1000-1
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 168-1; //Change Orig 1 Sek: 16800-1
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM10, &TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure);

    TIM_OCStructInit(&TIM_OCInitStructure);
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 0;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_Low;
    TIM_OC1Init(TIM10, &TIM_OCInitStructure);

    TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM10, TIM_OCPreload_Enable);
    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM10, ENABLE);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM10, ENABLE);
    TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(TIM10, ENABLE);

    TIM10->CCR1 = 5;
}
```

Comment: How did you manage to write the 10us counter? Everything you need is there. You have three options to achieve your goal: Changing the clock division (might not be possible because it is often only possible in 2-complements), the timer period or the prescaler. Now do some math and your done.

Answer (score 0):

```
TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Period = 1;
TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 84-1;
```

it should work

Comment: Hi there, while this technically might answer the question, an explanation of why or how it does would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are three registers: PSC, CCR and ARR. The PWM frequency is calculated as follows:

PWM_freq = APBx_freq / (PSC+1)(ARR+1)

Duty Cycle = CCR / ARR

Assuming the APBx_freq = 168 MHz, setting PSC = 0 and ARR = 167, gives a PWM with 1us period and maximum possible duty cycle resolution, i.e: 1/167 = 0.59%. 
Increasing the ARR, decreases the frequency but increases the duty cycle resolution. This relationship, is unfortunately, nonlinear.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was, I don't need a PWM signal, I need a 1 us timer (`TIM10->CNT`).
A PWM signal was used to debug the frequency.
The right options are:

```c
TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Period = 0xFFFF;
TIM_TimeBaseInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 84-1;
TIM10->CCR1 = 1<<15;
```